# Why do I see  as content when accessing css rules in JS?

Tags: javascript, css

part of my css file:

```
.icon-activity_needs_assessment:before {
    content: "\e600";
}
```

this is what I see in console when accessing the css rules in javascript:

```
CSSStyleRule {
  cssText: ".icon-activity_needs_assessment::before { content: ""; }"
  parentRule: null
  parentStyleSheet: CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null, cssRules: CSSRuleList, rules: CSSRuleList, type: "text/css", href: "http://localhost:3000/humanitarian-icons.css", …}
  selectorText: ".icon-activity_needs_assessment::before"
  style: CSSStyleDeclaration {0: "content", alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
  styleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 1}
  type: 1
  __proto__: CSSStyleRule
}
```

Why do I see `content: "";` instead of `content: "\e600";`? I have many css classes like that and for each one I see `{ content: ""; }` in JS. Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: You *are* seeing what's in your style rule. Your rule includes that Unicode escape, and the browser is showing you that character.

Comment: https://utf8-icons.com/utf-8-character-58880

Comment: @Pointy How can I extract the icon code then?

Comment: What do you mean "extract"?  Your CSS source code requests a string with the UTF-16 character E600, and that's what you've got.

Comment: I don't understand the issue.  Normally people are *happy* when their browser renders Unicode characters for them.  If you want the original `\e600`, load the CSS source file outside the debugger.

Comment: Hm, and why do I not see the correct symbols when I also have the necessary font?

Comment: The code E600 is in the "private use area".  If your element is styled with a font that includes a glyph for that code point, then you'll see the glyph when the `:before` content is rendered. You will *not* see that glyph when you're looking at the style rule, because the browser uses its own default font in the console etc.